# Outlook VBA ignores original If argument when Else argument is added

Tags: vba, if-statement, outlook, contacts

Here is the original code that is working as intended:

```
Dim ContactsFolder As Folder
Set ContactsFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
Dim SearchContactName As String
Set myItem = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim NewContactEmail As String
Dim NewMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set NewMail = Application.ActiveInspector.currentItem

' Ask user for inputs
SearchContactName = InputBox("What is the name of your contact you want to comment to on Trello?")

Dim Contact As ContactItem

'search contacts'
For Each Contact In ContactsFolder.Items
    If Contact.FullName = SearchContactName Then
        If Contact.IMAddress = "" Then 'add trello card link'
            Contact.IMAddress = InputBox("What is the Trello card e-mail of this contact?")
            Contact.Save
            myItem.To = Contact.IMAddress
        Else
            myItem.To = Contact.IMAddress
        End If
    End If
Next

myItem.Body = NewMail.Body
myItem.Subject = NewMail.Subject

myItem.Display
```

My intention for this is that when it finds a contact, it will see if it has anything in the IMaddress. If it does have a link, then that will go into the "To:" of the e-mail. If it doesn't, outlook will prompt the user for a link, save the contact information and add the link to the "To:" of the e-mail. Like I said before, this code works as intended for any contacts that are in outlook, with or without a IMaddress.

The trouble I run into is when there is no contact information saved. Here is the code as stripped down as I could replicate the error:

```
Sub LeaveAComment()
Dim ContactsFolder As Folder
Set ContactsFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
Dim SearchContactName As String
Set myItem = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim NewContactEmail As String
Dim NewMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set NewMail = Application.ActiveInspector.currentItem

' Ask user for inputs
SearchContactName = InputBox("What is the name of your contact you want to comment to on Trello?")

Dim Contact As ContactItem

'search contacts'
For Each Contact In ContactsFolder.Items
    If Contact.FullName = SearchContactName Then
        If Contact.IMAddress = "" Then 'add trello card link'
            Contact.IMAddress = InputBox("What is the Trello card e-mail of this contact?")
            Contact.Save
            myItem.To = Contact.IMAddress
        Else
            myItem.To = Contact.IMAddress
        End If
    Else
        If MsgBox("Contact does not exist. Would you like to add one?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
            End
        Else
            End
        End If
    End If
Next

myItem.Body = NewMail.Body
myItem.Subject = NewMail.Subject

myItem.Display
```

It is when I add the

```
Else
        If MsgBox("Contact does not exist. Would you like to add one?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
            End
        Else
            End
        End If
End If
```

that I run into problems. Now when I run the macro, the msgbox will trigger no matter if the Contact already exists or not. For some reason the original If Contact.FullName  = SearchContactName is being overridden by the Else, even though the Else shouldn't be triggered (at least in my thought process). I've tried reversing the logic and doing:

```
For Each Contact In ContactsFolder.Items
    If Contact.FullName <> SearchContactName Then
```

But that brought out the same outcome.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't place the following part of the code inside for each loop:

```
Else
    If MsgBox("Contact does not exist. Would you like to add one?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
        End
    Else
        End
    End If
End If
```

Let's assume you have 100 contacts and want to find one named "Charlie". The part of the code above gives the message box, saying that the contact does not exist after checking only 1 out of 100 contacts.

You have to place the message box outside of the loop. You can use boolean to check if "Charlie" contact was found:

```
Dim contactFound as boolean
For Each Contact In ContactsFolder.Items
   If Contact.FullName = SearchContactName Then
      contactFound = true
```

Then just after the loop:

```
  If contactFound = false then
      If MsgBox("Contact does not exist. Would you like to add one?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
         End
      Else
         End
      End If
  End if
```